# how to change the value of Math.PI

Tags: java, math

I'm lead developer of a scientific app. We have a new requirement from accounting that pi=3.14. But in JAVA Math.PI=3.14159... I tried changing it with reflection. But it seems that doesn't work, some of the libraries we call *still* use the old value of pi. For example when we integrate 1/(x*x+1) it still comes out 3.14159... not 3.14. I have tried everything...please, how can I change Math.PI???

Edit: Here's an exerpt from our company wide accounting standards.

> For compliance reasons, all numerical constants must be accurate to exactly two digits after the decimal point, and all calculations must be carried out accordingly and consistent with this level of accuracy.

I specifically asked about pi, they said yes, pi must be accurate to exactly two decimal digits...

Comment: Does accounting also want to change the value of e, the natural logarithm, to 2? Sorry, not a professional thing to say, but your question begs the question of why accounting wants to do this? Otherwise create your own constant, say `Accounting.PI`, give it your own value, and then re-assign all constants within the program.

Comment: They didn't want `22 / 7`?

Comment: Sorry...I just want to change Math.PI and have it work everywhere. Like in my code and in _all_ libraries. We use jblas colt and commons math.

Comment: rgettman no, 22/7 is 3.1428... we need 3.14 exactly

Comment: why don't just ask them to remove the stupid requirement?

Comment: Even if you could redefine `Math.PI`, integrating `2/(x*x+1)` would still get you 3.14159...  That's got nothing to do with Java...

Comment: A "scientific" app where pi is 3.14. (What...?)

Comment: jingx that's what I'm saying...how do I get integral of 1/(x*x+1) from -inf to inf = 3.14?

Comment: And just when did accountants get put in charge of science?

Comment: @b4904878 you can’t change the output of an integral, it is clearly defined. If you do want to change it, besides defying the concept of math in our universe, you would have to convince a long line of dead people dating back to Archimedes to change some texts they have written.

Comment: So the value of PI is defined by accountants, not mathematicians. TIL

Comment: Is your company based in Indiana, perchance?

Comment: You can only imagine how badly the engineers have failed when accounting has to request that! :D

Comment: When you perform a mathematical computation, you can output the result to whatever number of digits you require. It's called FORMATTING. Note that there is a difference between representing PI as a sequence of digits and the value itself.

Comment: Wasn't April 1 a few months ago?

Comment: out of curiosity, which app is this?

Comment: Code-Apprentice _all calculations_ need to be as if _all constants_ are accurate to 2 places...not just the result. Reblochon Masque this is internal risk modeling and optimization

Comment: When dealing with money you'd better switch to BigDecimal, or similar. And you'd have to find alternatives for the libraries then.

Comment: @b4904878 _"accurate to 2 places"_ that's a wild requirement for constants in a scientific environment. Is it dependent on units?

Comment: This has to be a joke or a terrible misinterpretation of requirements.

Comment: OK, got it - it is one of those [fool's errands](http://messybeast.com/dragonqueen/fools-errands.htm) that juniors are sent to complete with no chance of success.

Comment: related: [The State of Indiana nearly passed a law which would have made Pi equal 3.2 - strange but true](https://youtu.be/bFNjA9LOPsg), [That Time Pi was Almost Legally Changed to 3.2 or 4](https://youtu.be/Qf0x3w-snno)

Answer (score 20):

Short answer is:  You can't change `Math.PI` using reflection, or any other way.

The `Math.PI` constant is a compile-time constant, and as the JLS explains ([JLS 17.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3)):

> "If a `final` field is initialized to a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) in the field declaration, changes to the final field may not be observed, since uses of that final field are replaced at compile time with the value of the constant expression."

If you have a requirement for a PI constant whose value is different to the standard, you need to define your own constant in your own class or interface.

---

Unfortunately, defining your own PI may not be sufficient for the people who issued this edict ... since standard and 3rd-party math libraries will be implemented to use the mathematically correct values for pi, e, and so on.  Finding / fixing all of these would basically require implementing your own JVM.

But here's a "constructive" solution.  Don't support a `PI` constant in your calculator at all.  Instead, support a `pi()` function ... which returns a full precision value.  And if "they" object, make the value returned by `pi()` depend on a command-line option or something.

Alternatively, just do the sensible thing and ignore this crazy edict.  For example, you say that the edict comes from the company wide standard for *accounting* software.  You are writing a *scientific* application, so you could argue that "accounting rules" do not apply<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Certainly, anyone with significant scientific or mathematical knowledge will tell you that they *should not* apply.</sup>

Comment: _"Alternatively, just do the sensible thing and ignore this crazy edict."_ That was what I was doing when confronted with a similar requirement (change the value of the gravitational constant in an engineering application). Would have been crazy to implement and impossible to test.

Answer (score -6):

If the `Math.PI` defined as `Double`, u can change it by use reflect.

Comment: How is this different from Stephen's answer? Also, this wouldn't change results obtained from libraries or internal functions that don't rely on the constant.